# Location Accuracy Reduced on Apple Watch Ultra

Tags: location, apple-watch, watchos

I have been observing a strange behavior on my Apple Watch Ultra.

Device Environment:

```
Apple Watch Ultra on Watch OS 10 Beta
Offline
Disconnected from companion iPhone
Workout active: "Walking"
```

Expected behavior:

The workout should record accurate locations (with accuracy of approximately 3-4 meters). This level of accuracy is already being achieved in the same watch (verified using several GPS status apps) when a workout is not active.

Observed behavior:

Accuracy as good as 2 meter is observed when no workouts are active, but as soon as the workout starts, the accuracy drops to a maximum of 14 meters and never gets better than this. This is confirmed to be happening every single time and is verified using several GPS status apps during the workout.

Does anyone else has faced similar behavior?